# typeof abstract class and extendors

Tags: typescript

So I have a couple of classes

```js
abstract class Base {
  private readonly prop = "abc";
}

class One extends Base {
  // ...
}

class Two extends Base {
  // ...
}
```

and I want to create a type so I can store either the `Base` class or any class that extends it(not an instance of them). First, I thought that just `let c: Base` would work but that obviously expects an instance of that class not the class itself. Then, I tried `let c: typeof Base` but when assigning `One` to that variable, tsc generates an error. So what type should I use in variable `c`?

Comment: Can you also include the error in your post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Base` is an abstract class, `typeof Base` will not actually contain a callable constructor signature, just the statics and the prototype of the class. This is usually a good thing since we want to disallow instantiation of the type.

You can intersect `typeof Base` with a constructor signature, this willhave the effect of surfacing the base constructor:

```
abstract class Base {
  public constructor(private readonly prop = "abc") { }
}

class One extends Base {
  p: string;
}

class Two extends Base {
  p2: string;
}

declare let ctor: typeof Base & (new (...a: any[]) => Base); 
new ctor("") // ok
class D extends ctor { } // ok
ctor = One; //ok
```

This solution will force you to have the same constructor signature in the derived classes you want to assign, So this is an error

```
abstract class Base {
  public constructor(private readonly prop = "abc") { }
}

class One extends Base {
  public constructor(prop: string, p: string) {
    super(prop)
  }
}

declare let ctor: typeof Base & (new (...a: any[]) => Base);
ctor = One; //err, new One requires more params
```

If you don't need the statics of `Base` you can just use the constructor signature

```
declare let ctor: new (...a: any[]) => Base;
ctor = One; //ok for any derived type regardless of ctor params.
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks again for the awesome explanation!