# Typescript create property that describes a type of type, which is based on abstract type

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to figure out generics and do a particular case where I store a type based off another type and then at runtime create it.

- I've seen this and my interface fails w/ my property:
  [typeof abstract class and extendors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56053619/typeof-abstract-class-and-extendors)
- I'm also trying to understand:
  https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html

I've done a crappy way, but I know there has to be a better approach.

What I want:

```
abstract class AFruit{
   isBad:boolean;
}

class Apple extends AFruit {}
class Orange extends AFruit {}

//problem
interface Storage
{
   fruit: type-base-of-abstract-fruit; //this is what I'd like to figure out
}

//my version
interface Storage
{
   fruit: typeof Apple | typeof Orange;
}


//finally, my example usage:
{fruit: Apple}
//or
{fruit: Orange}
```

I do want to later on new it up to use Apple or Orange, but I just haven't figured out the typescript generics way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intent is eventually to construct an instance via `new` and passing in no parameters, then you want `Storage`'s `fruit` property to have a [newable](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/callable#newable) signature, like this:

```
interface Storage {
    fruit: new () => AFruit
}
```

This will work for your example usages:

```
const a: Storage = { fruit: Apple }; // okay
const o: Storage = { fruit: Orange }; // okay
```

And it will fail to work if you try to assign something that does not construct an `AFruit` instance when called via `new` with no parameters.  This breaks:

```
const oops: Storage = { fruit: AFruit }; // error, abstract
```

because `AFruit` is `abstract` and has no exposed newable signature.  And this breaks:

```
class Tomato extends AFruit {
    constructor(public isItReallyAFruit: boolean) {
        super();
    }
}
const stillOops: Storage = { fruit: Tomato }; // error, bad ctor args
```

because `Tomato` is a class constructor requiring a single `boolean` argument when called with `new` (e.g., `new Tomato(true);`).

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAsAFBFKlIgBGUALgE4LVLwYhRRICCAYrQK4CWjAoTKik-KACEQAEwBcSCgHslGCCGBIAvEgBmmKBADcJMgF8ip0s1bsOMGGqQQAHtQjAZdngKFWxINpIAIwmIub+NmxIAPL0wADmyK7unt58gnj+okpBAExhohbE4aQA9GUwtEoUamD+-MDutPqISADK1Er0SXhI2WS6GdQKwBAA7kgAFACU2gB8nD6C-sWiFWAAnkgAbhC0UPxKwJalTMc05Aqd3SC9Orh6wwr2jshmRkgVSEoA1iCbSIXRhKa5dHrIB5PXwKOIaXofL5lH7-QFneDAn5KGBQMG3e59IYwpbDJCI777aq0AA05CodAYp1EUXYABUlGAQF1nG4PF4Sb4smdmcC+PBwVMYLxavx4OIoABJagAJXUGAwm24z0UKjUGjmwjERqQUF4MH2s0KxrWEXRmJo-HVMWxuI64LukMJ2vZnO55ORlO6tIosiY4PItASUFOZiAA)

Comment: Thank you, @jcalz! It took me a while to understand, and also I oversimplified this example too. Let me ask you this too. I was looking back again at the referenced stackoverflow and they added `new (...a: any[])` where they pass in arguments. I know this is generic, but how would you write that if the arguments were always `ctor(string, boolean, number)`?

Comment: `new (a: string, b: boolean, c: number) => AFruit` would work I think

Comment: Thank you again! I'm really enjoying typescript more over es6+; especially since my experience w/ c# prior, but it's still super new to me. Again, thanks for the help a lot!